# .MapWhen executing for all calls

Tags: asp.net-core, middleware, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a large already running application built on .net core 1.0.4. I have a need to add a micro api to this application, and am attempting to integrate a fairly simple http basic auth middleware into the pipeline **only** for calls to the api controller.

In my `startup.cs`configure method, I have the following.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {            
        //run basic auth only on API calls           
        app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase), appBuilder =>
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<BasicAuthenticationMiddleware>();
            app.UseMvc();
        });


        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/site/error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();            

        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStatusCodePages();            

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Site}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
        });


    }
```

It's my understanding that the pipeline would branch for all calls that start with /api into the Basic middle ware. My issue is that with this code, ALL calls regardless of the path are hitting the `.MapWhen` path, and essentially breaking the entire site.

Comment: You forgot to use appBuilder inside your MapWhen

Comment: @Tratcher good catch, that was it. Thanks a million!